# Expression can not contain lambda expression Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, sum

[image]

I have data-table and i am trying to find sum of columns where Id starts with Particular value.I have tried some ways but getting error.

```
result=Convert.ToInt32(dtNew.Compute("Sum(ResPending)", "Substring(ID,0,1)='G'"));//error shows-- Substring() argument is out of range
```

And tried this way also

```
dtNew.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ID").ToString().StartsWith("G"));//Expression can not contain lambda expression
```

Comment: The latter *looks* like it should be okay - please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, including the code to set up the table with dummy data. (You don't need the `ToString()` call, btw. Your `Field<string>()`  method call already returns a string.)

Comment: I suspect you executed the latter in Visual Studio "watch" window, no?

Comment: `//Expression can not contain lambda expression` this error usually when you try lambda in _Watch_ window, are you try it in code directly?

Comment: @har07,yes i have executed in watch window and it show the above error.

Comment: Related thread : [VS debugging “quick watch” tool and lambda expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725499/vs-debugging-quick-watch-tool-and-lambda-expressions)

Comment: @sharad as Jon Skeet's wrote, your code looks fine and might work in the body of your program, only VS watch doesn't support evaluating lambda expression

Comment: @har07 correction. VS upto and including 2013 does not support lambda expressions in the watcher.

Comment: sustring index starts with 1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049995/using-substringexpression-startindex-length-with-bindingsource-on-datacolu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
Substring(ID,1,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("sum(ResPending)", "ID LIKE 'G*'"));
```

//this works for me.

```
dtNew.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ID").ToString().StartsWith("G"));
```

this also works.

Below is the test code:

```
 Random ran = new Random();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("ResPending", typeof(Int32));
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                dr[0] = "G123" + i;
            }
            else
            {
                dr[0] = i;
            }

            dr[1] = "an";
            dr[2] = ran.Next(1, 100);
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        int result = 0;
        //// result =  Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("sum(ResPending)", "ID LIKE 'G*'"));
        ////result   = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("Sum(ResPending)", "Substring(ID,0,1)='G'")); ////this throws error. as index is 1 based
        var k  = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ID").ToString().StartsWith("G"));
```

Comment: It works because you're enumerating the data into a collection. It's a solution, but it might be hard on resources if the table is particularly big. I'd suggest enumerating only the ID's, then filter the ones you want, and then doing a second Where..In to get the records back. It should be much gentler on the resources, even though you're doing an extra DB query.

Comment: you saying about below line : 
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ID").ToString().StartsWith("G"))

Comment: The problem is that AsEnumerable() immediately executes a SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT.

Comment: I was just testing the code , I will never be using AsEnumerable in this case, as we can filter the record with inbuilt filters. It was just to validate the code.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code returns 3 `DataRows`:

```
var coll = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(k => k.Field<string>(0).Contains("G")).Select(p => p).ToList();
```

Is this what you want?